# configuration.optimization has an unknown property 'chunkIds'

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

i use webpack v4, i see optimization.chunkIds field in doc: https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationchunkids. but when i use in webpack.config.js i get an err;

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.optimization has an unknown property 'chunkIds'. These properties are valid:
   object { removeAvailableModules?, removeEmptyChunks?, mergeDuplicateChunks?, flagIncludedChunks?, occurrenceOrder?, sideEffects?, providedExports?, usedExports?, concatenateModules?, splitChunks?, runtimeChunk?, noEmitOnErrors?, namedModules?, namedChunks?, portableRecords?, minimize?, minimizer?, nodeEnv? }
   -> Enables/Disables integrated optimizations
```

my webpack.config.js is about:

```
...
optimization: {
  chunkIds: 'named'
}
```

i use "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10", "webpack": "^4.1.0"

i try to change webpack version number, under v4,but it not work; i cant upgrdate to v5, because i need change a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it worked for me. I came across a similar problem and i solved it by removing the typo in my code. So check your file for any typo and make sure that you type

```
optimization: {
    chunkIds: 'named'
  },
```

accordingly. If the error persists, Leave a comment and i will help out